# Nginx + php5-fpm = "File not found"

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, socket

I've hit a wall whilst setting up a site using nginx / fpm. The page displays "File not found", and this appears in the nginx error.log:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream
```

I'm new to both nginx and fpm, and that error message means nothing to me (even the google machine hasn't helped!). Can anyone shed any light onto what could be happening?

Comment: Could you add the part of your nginx config where you defin the PHP handling?

Comment: For me the following article helped: http://nginxlibrary.com/resolving-no-input-file-specified-error/. Generally this error comes if there is a problem with the `SCRIPT_FILENAME`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should have a `location` section to handle PHP requests configured similarly to this:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include         fastcgi_params;
    }
```

(The extra `try_files` resolves a [security vulnerability](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,88845,88845) which could allow arbitrary files to be executed as PHP.)

In addition, your `root` should be defined in the `server` section of the configuration file, **not** the `location` section. This is one of the most common [nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

Comment: +1 for that misconfigurations article - really worth a read, particularly if you're learning Nginx. Well written, entry-level, with several great tips!

Answer (score 2):

This is a note for passenger installs.

I just installed nginx from source via passenger which caused a problem with php5-fpm. The default nginx.conf makes use of the problem described by Michael Hampton. The solution is to remove the blok around the root and index directives, so:

```
location / {
    root html
    index index.html index.htm
}
```

becomes:

```
root html
index index.html index.htm
```

Furthermore the php block is incorrectly set up. See Michael Hamptons answer for the correct way to it.

An additional note could be that if php5-fpm is set up to use sockets point the fastcgi_pass parameter in the php block in nginx.conf to the socket setup in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf.

Answer (score 2):

I Just had this problem in a new version of nginx. (config taken from an older version)

What I had to do was place the `include fastcgi_params;` above my custom `SCRIPT_FILENAME` like this:

```
location @web {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;
}
```

As the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` was being overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using aliases in your location blocks, an unhandled 404 error can also exhibit this behavior. You can see this if the page displayed in the browser is the simple text "File not found" as opposed to the prettier formatted (centered) nginx 404 page. Essentially, it's really saying the 404 page can't be found.

To solve, add an additional `try_files $uri =404` line in your location block and reload the nginx config. In addition to what [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) said about [solving a specific security vulnerability](https://serverfault.com/a/406169/214507), this also allows the fastcgi handler to override the alias definition and find the 404 script in the default location.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo vim /etc/php-fpm.conf
```

about line 149, change php user && user group

I test it successful now.

Comment: This is way is right! Hey man, you can try it!

Comment: When you change the user and group, You don't forget to restart php-fpm.If you use centos6 you can use this command:  sudo service php-fpm restart

Answer (score 0):

I have seen :

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading
>   response header from upstream

in a server I placed under high load when stress testing. My suspicion, still to be confirmed, is that the available file handles from the OS were exhausted. In which case php-fpm cannot get a reference to the file.

I realise this is speculative but it certainly fits my scenario and might also help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks @homeway, Your answer inspire me. Thank you very much!
>
> I  meet the same question, But Other method didn't help me resolve the
>   question!
>
> I  resolve it, I find the key is that:  **Linux User Right lead to the
>   question:   FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"**
>
> Because The PHP-FPM default user:group is  apache:apache,  But your
>   code dir is someBody:someBody. So you should change the User right!
>
> I write a blog to resolve this question, You can see this blog:
>
> [Nginx FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"][1] `   [1]:
>   http://geekhades.blogspot.com/2017/06/nginx-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-primary.html