# trouble executing php scripts with nginx

Tags: nginx

My nginx config looks like this

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
           root /var/www;
           index index.php index.html;
           autoindex on; 
        }

        location /folder1 {
           root   /var/www/folder1;
           index  index.php index.html index.htm;
           try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location /folder2 {
           root   /var/www/folder2;
           index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

The problem with the above setup is that i am not able to execute php files. Now as per my understanding of nginx config rules, when i am in my webroot(`/`) which is `/var/www` the value of `$document_root` becomes `/var/www` so when i request for `localhost/hi.php` the `fastcgi_param` `SCRIPT_FILENAME` becomes `/var/www/hi.php` and that is the actual path of the php script. But when i actully go to the url `localhost/hi.php` i get a message `File not found.` But when I go to the url `localhost/hi.html` i can see the html output of the page. So this means that there is a problem with the location block of php.

Similarly when i request for `localhost/folder1/hi.php` the `$document_root` becomes `/var/www/folder1` because this is specified as the root in `folder`'s location block so again the `fastcgi_param` `SCRIPT_FILENAME` becomes `/var/www/folder1/hi.php`. But when i actully go to the url `localhost/folder1/hi.php` i get a message `File not found.` But when I go to the url `localhost/folder1/hi.html` i can see the html output of the page. So again php are not being executed.

Please help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `root` lines from the two `location /folder*` blocks, and move the `root /var/www` to within the `server` block, not the `location /` block. This is one of the most common [nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

Comment: I read the link you pointed to but could not get this line `If you add a root to every location block then a location block that isn't matched will have no root`. If a location block is not matched then whether it has a root or not shouldn't matter. And in my above config all location blocks i specify have a root

Comment: Heck I'll give you +1 here for the same reason as I did here: http://serverfault.com/questions/406158/nginx-php5-fpm-file-not-found/406169#406169 - that article is great!