# nginx php5-fpm "File not found" -- FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

so I'm trying to run for the first time the nginx web server with php5-fpm on a debian wheezy server

Hitting a php file display simply `File not found`

I have done my research (waste a lot of hours actually ;), there are a lot of people that have similar problems, yet I didn't succeed to correct it with what worked for them.

I still have the same error :

`$ tail  /var/log/nginx/access.log /var/log/nginx/error.log /var/log/php5-fpm.log | less`

==> `/var/log/nginx/error.log` <==

> 2013/10/26 21:36:00 **[error] 6900#0: *1971 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"** *while reading response header from upstream,*

I have tried a lot of things, it's hard to remember what.

I have put my config files on github

- [**my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf**](https://gist.github.com/internaciulo/7172230)
- [**my /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf**](https://gist.github.com/internaciulo/7174822)

Currently, the nginx.conf configuration uses this...

```
server {
  server_name mydomain.tld;
  root /srv/data1/test;

   location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

`/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` contains 
`listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`

I have tried the unix socket version, same thing.
  `fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`

I made sure the server is started

`$ netstat -alnp | grep LISTEN`

> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN      6913/php-fpm.conf)   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306
>   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4785/mysqld        tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:842             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>   2286/inetd         tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111
>   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2812/rpcbind       tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>   5710/nginx         tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22
>   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2560/sshd          tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>   5710/nginx         tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*
>   LISTEN      2812/rpcbind       unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM
>   LISTENING     323648   6574/tmux           /tmp//tmux-1000/default
>   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     619072
>   6790/fcgiwrap       /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket     unix  2      [ ACC ] 
>   SEQPACKET  LISTENING     323      464/udevd
>   /run/udev/control     unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING
>   610686   2812/rpcbind        /var/run/rpcbind.sock     unix  2      [
>   ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     318633   4785/mysqld
>   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Each time I modify the nginx.conf file, I make sure to relaunch this command

`nginx -t && nginx -s reload && echo "nginx configuration reloaded"`

and same thing for php5-fpm

`/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart`

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Sources that didn't help

- http://serverfault.com/questions/406158/nginx-php5-fpm-file-not-found
- http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
- http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil
- https://gist.github.com/internaciulo/7172230
- http://kemovitra.blogspot.fr/2013/10/enabling-status-page-for-php5-fpm.html

Comment: all you posted here looks okay to me. What does your config for the fpm pool look like? Do you chroot it into some directory?

Comment: What script are you trying to run, and where did you put it in your filesystem?

Comment: @etagenklo thanks. I didn't do anything special for the fpm pool. I've just put [my /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf](https://gist.github.com/internaciulo/7175247) on github

Comment: @MichaelHampton I put them in a non-standard directory in /srv/data1/test  they are simpe php files that call phpinfo() for example. Before I wanted to run Dokuwiki and Dotclear.

Comment: get rid of this:
`chroot = /var/www`

Comment: Wow, that whas it. I don't know how I can express my gratitude :) I can't even approve your answer since comments do not count for reputation  ;)

Comment: @etagenklo Make it an answer :)

Comment: Ok, I did that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the

`chroot = /var/www`

in your fpm-pool configuration. Otherwise php-fpm won't be able to access /srv.

Comment: Brillant, that was it !