# Nginx + php5-fpm + Symfony2 = "File not found."

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, symfony

This is the site config based on [official Symfony2 doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx)

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name     project.local;
    root            /media/Storage/project/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    server_name     project.local;
    root            /media/Storage/project/web;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.key;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

At first, I was getting `No input file specified.` error, however I've read on [nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Symfony) that for this config I don't need the `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0` (actually, they say Symfony2 needs it to be `cgi.fix_pathinfo=1`).

So I've changed it back to default (`1`) and now I'm getting `File not found.`.

I've seen [other questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/406158/nginx-php5-fpm-file-not-found) where they suggest to use `location ~ \.php$ {`, however they were not meant for Symfony2 app.

I'd like to stick with the Symfony2 official config if possible.

Why is this happening, and what is the solution?

**EDIT 1:**

I've changed the `cgi.fix_pathinfo` back to `0` and changed the config to this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name     project.local;
    root            /media/Storage/project/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ "^(.+\.php)($|/)" {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name     project.local;
    root            /media/Storage/project/web;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.key;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ "^(.+\.php)($|/)" {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$; 
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

Then restarted nginx and php5-fpm, as suggested on IRC, however, getting the famous `Input file not specified` error.

**EDIT 2:** this is the error.log

> 2014/06/25 22:11:45 [error] 11922#0: *3 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /media/Storage/project/web/app_dev.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: project.local, request: "GET /app_dev.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "project.local"

**EDIT 3:** this is access.log

> 127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jun/2014:22:11:45 +0200] "GET /app_dev.php HTTP/1.1" 404 56 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/34.0.1847.116 Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36"

The symfony2 log files are empty. I don't think symfony was ever executed.

**EDIT 4:** I've changed my confing following [this SO anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998856/nginx-friendly-php-framework/6750433#6750433) to:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name     project.local;
    root            /media/Storage/project/web;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        index app.php;
        if (-f $request_filename) {
          break;
        }
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php last;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ (app|app_dev).php {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name     project.local;
    root            /media/Storage/project/web;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.key;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl_access.log;

    location / {
        index app.php;
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
        }
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php last;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ (app|app_dev).php {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

And now I'm getting `Access denied.` error. Yay, something changed :). Boo, not working yet :(.

**EDIT 5:** I've `chown loostro:www-data /media/Storage/project -R` and then `chmod g+s /media/Storage/project -R`, still getting `Access denied`

**EDIT 6**: The `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock` permissions are:

`srw-rw----  1  www-data  www-data  0  cze 26 11:03  php5-fpm.sock`

The `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` file is the default (for Ubuntu 14.04 distro), except these changes I've uncommented following a tutorial:

```
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
```

Comment: Is it a 404 Page not found error? What software generates the error? What are the entries in access.log and error.log?

Comment: I believe it's php5-fpm that generates this error.

Comment: In your config you dont add the index directive,, maybe that fail.

Comment: Without all log entries (nginx access.log, error.log, Symfony logs) we cannot help you.

Comment: added error log and access log

Comment: Whats your fpm pool configuration look like? Did you set perms for the socket or change the user from the default, and do they match up appropriately?

Comment: @prodigitalson see edit6, updated question

Comment: @loostro I have my `listen.mode` set to `0666` which i think was the default when i first set everything up. The dedault may have changed because they thought `0660` was more sensible, but Id be curious if making it `0666` would solve the issue. At least then you would know where the issue was. Also in my configuration, both owner and group match the owner and group of the files I'm serving. Of course I have mine set up to run as specific user accounts, not the system `www-data`.

Comment: @prodigitalson it was project file priviledges in my case. I was able to run the app (which displayed another error.. but I have not yet imported my database, so this was expected). Anyways.. after fixing priviledges (see top of my question, "Summary") I finally see Application errors instead of ngninx errors.

Comment: Confirmed, after adding `fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;` and `fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;` (to fix 502 Bad Gateway error) and improting the database, the app works flawlessly! Now I need to lower the priviledges and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SUMMARY**: My issue was wrong file permissions. The official symfony2 [config for nginx](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx) is OK. I moved my files to an NTFS Storage drive, and it seems during the move file permissions were changed.

- `chown loostro:www-data -R /media/Storage/project` - change owner to loostro and group to www-data (loostro is my user under which I develop the app, php5-fpm runs as www-data), recursively
- `chmod 755 -R /media/Storage/project` - change file permissions for project to rwx (owner) rx (group, other), recursively
- `cd /media/Storage/project` enter my project directory
- `chmod 775 -R app/cache app/logs web/uploads private/uploads` - change file permissions for uploadable directories rwx (owner,group) and rx (other), recursively
- `chmod g+s -R /media/Storage/project` - keep user and group & file permissions for newly created files in directories, recursively