# Nginx error: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream

Tags: centos, nginx, web-server, php-fpm

I have installed Nginx 1.6.2 with PHP-FPM (PHP 5.5.18) under CentOS 6.6 server. I didn't touch nothing else but `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file where I made some changes (see below):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  webvm devserver ;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files      $uri =404;
        root           /var/www/html;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

After restart Nginx and try to access `http://devserver/index.php` file I get this error:

> 2014/12/01 19:48:51 [error] 5014#0: *6 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 192.168.3.1, server: webvm, request: "GET /index.php
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "devserver"

I have checked also permissions/owner for `/var/www/html` with `ls -l` command and this is the output:

```
#ls -l /var/www/html/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23 Dec  1 19:29 index.php
```

I did not touch anything under PHP-FPM pool so `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` have the default configuration:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
user = apache
group = apache
```

Could be permissions the issue?

I have read several posts here (as for example [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/517190/nginx-1-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-primary-script-unknown),[2](https://serverfault.com/questions/406158/nginx-php5-fpm-file-not-found),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194196/1-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-primary-script-unknown)) talking around the same error and possible solutions and tried to apply to my situation but can't get it to works so I need some help here from any, what I'm doing wrong?

**Note:** I get out commented lines from the file showed since aren't relevant

Comment: `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;` did you just make that up? _does_ the file `/scripts/index.php` exist?

Comment: @AD7six nope, that's the problem I forgot to change that line to `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;` which means set the right path, thanks for your tip

Comment: I had this issue in OS X after successfully setting it up on a Amazon Linux instance.  I used a $document_root$fastcgi_sript_name; but after exhausting all other permission and service checks I finally just added root /usr/local/var/www/domainname; and bang it started working.  Only sharing this comment as I was pulling my hair out for 3 days with a similar issue even though root was defined elsewhere in the .conf file.

Answer (score 0):

For me issue with `"Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream` was, that one of php extensions got uninstalled, while it's config was still on disk (specifically it was redis module). Checking `/etc/php/XX/pool.d/*` against what modules have config (.ini files) and should be installed (or config should be removed) fixed issue. After installing one missing module all started to work again.

It wasn't NGINX fault, but PHP extensions issue.

Answer (score -1):

change www.conf

```
user = nginx 
group = nginx
```

change fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name; into

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

and also check, do you have httacess file in /var/www/html. usually this cause that problem

Comment: Why change the php-fpm user, how are .htaccess files relevant when using nginx..?